# Почему-то текст в Android Studio ведёт себя не так, как мной ожидалось

Tags: android, android-studio, design

1. Пытаюсь (по видеокурсу) прикрепить текст к тексту:
   [image: перетаксивая стрелочку с этого кружочка к другому тексту]
2. Выбираю end:

[image: Start to textView2 end]

3. И текст почему-то куда-то улетает:

[image: в левый верхний бок за пределы экрана]

Что я делаю не так? Спасибо!

Comment: Дизайнер капризная штука. Без правки макета в текстовом виде практически не обойтись.

Comment: сменил id textView и всё зарабоотало......

Comment: спасибо вам  )

Comment: Лучше привыкай писать ручками. И другим понятней будет, а то скинул пару скриншотов, по которым ничего не понять)